# ¿A que se debe este error?, Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in....linea de error

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Clave</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellidos</th>
                <th>Formación Académica</th>
                <th>Dirección</th>
                <th>Correo</th>
                <th>Teléfono</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
         <tbody>
    <?php
      if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlDoc)) { //linea de error fetch array
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['clave'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['apellidos'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['formacion'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['direccion'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['correo'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['telefono'];?></td>
```

```html
function buscaDocente($clave)
{
global $connect;
$sqlDoc = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE clave = ".$clave);
return $sqlDoc;
}
```

Comment: trato de solo imprimir datos de un registro por consulta de un campo, la función select esta en un archivo aparte, y mando a traer esa función al archivo donde se le hace fetch_array, los nombres asociativos estan bien con los de la bd.

Comment: El mensaje se muestra cuando hay error en su consulta , probar de esta forma `$sqlDoc = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE clave = '$clave'");`

Comment: el error que sale capturado es:
Unknown column 'datoinsertado' in 'where clause'
Es un tipo de campo varchar, cuando inserto solo numero lo guarda bien, pero al poner alfanúmerico es cuando me sale el error.
Estoy pasando los datos de un formulario modal a un archivo php, con ajax. Y el archivo php que recibe los datos, los captura asi:
$clave=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect (strip_tags($_POST["clave"],ENT_QUOTES)));
No se si tenga que ver algo, por que no veo otra cosa.
Gracias Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Deberías tratar de imprimir el valor de `mysqli_error()` ya que esta devolviendo un `boolean` de seguro porque tienes un error en tu consulta.

```
$sqlDoc = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE clave = ".$clave) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: De acuerdo, ya la cambie ahora me imprime: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in...  linea de la consulta:

Comment: $sqlDoc = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM profesores WHERE clave = ".$clave) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: el error que sale capturado es:
Unknown column 'datoinsertado' in 'where clause'
Es un tipo de campo varchar, cuando inserto solo numero lo guarda bien, pero al poner alfanúmerico es cuando me sale el error.
Estoy pasando los datos de un formulario modal a un archivo php, con ajax. Y el archivo php que recibe los datos, los captura asi:
$clave=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect (strip_tags($_POST["clave"],ENT_QUOTES)));
No se si tenga que ver algo, por que no veo otra cosa.
Gracias Saludos

Comment: La columna 'datoinsertado' a la que hace referencia es un alias que usas dentro la consulta cierto?

Comment: 'datoinsertado' lo puse yo, pero lo que devuelve en realidad es el dato que trato de insertar en el input, y me devuelve en el mensaje lo que se intenta insertar