# Login de usuarios con php + angular + mysql error al iniciar sesión

Tags: php, angular

Tengo un login de usuarios con Angular + PHP + MySQL la cuestión es que actualmente tengo una API de prueba que si que me hace login.

El servicio de mi **login.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  public url:string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.url=GLOBAL.url;
  }

  // API DE PRUEBA
  logIn(username:string, password:string){
    var result = this.http.post<JSON>('https://reqres.in/api/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

El login para la API es el siguiente:

**Usuario:** `eve.holt@reqres.in`
**Contraseña:** `cityslicka`

La dirección de la API de prueba es la siguiente como podéis ver `https://reqres.in/api/login` yo he probado en mi API a hacer el login pero no me sale o algo hago mal.

```
// LOGIN
$app->post('/login', function () use ($db, $app) {
    $json = $app->request->post('json');
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    $username = $data['username'];
    $password = $data['password'];

    var_dump($username);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE username = $username AND password = $password";
    $query = $db->query($sql);

    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($filas > 0) {

      echo json_encode(['data' => 1, 'mensaje' => 'Ingreso exitoso']);
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(['data' => 0, 'mensaje' => 'no pudo']);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
});
```

El error que me tira es el siguiente:

**Type:** ErrorException
**Message:** mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Comment: Hola ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? ¿Te lanza algún error la petición?

Comment: Me dice lo siguiente: ``mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given`` en la línea 1444 que corresponde a lo siguiente ``$filas = mysqli_num_rows($query);``

Comment: Aquí podría estar tu solución. [Post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137935/warning-mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-boolean-g)